# Media Queries Ignored On Mobile Devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, wordpress-theming

I am working on making a theme mobile responsive. You can view it here, http://107.170.168.111/

When viewing on desktop and resizing the browser, it works fine. However, on actual mobile devices it doesn't seem to be working correctly (the sidebar should be hidden and a mobile nav should appear). It works on single post views such as: http://107.170.168.111/2015/04/27/szechuan-green-beans/#more-9327

but not on the actual index. I can't seem to figure out ***why***.

My media queries, of course, are at the end of my CSS document:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 640px){
        .hide-for-small{
            display: none !important;
        }
        .show-for-small{
            display: block !important;
        }

        .sidebar-container{
        display: none !important;
        }
        #sidebar{
        display: none !important;
        }
        .wrapper{
        width: 100%;
        }
        #content{
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 110px 0 0;
        }
    }
```

and in my `<head>` i have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

I'm pretty stumped, any suggestions? Thanks!

### Update:

`meta viewport` is located in header.php - which is included on index.php, but for some reason is not being displayed. The same code is used on single.php which works.

- Header.php -> https://gist.github.com/buschschwick/a7f67176e748c08e314a
- Single.php -> https://gist.github.com/buschschwick/d3e2bdff07fffcb4b01a
- Index.php -> https://gist.github.com/buschschwick/56576b2294b160271a3a

### Solved:

A disabled caching plugin was still serving the old version of index.php that did not include the `meta viewport`. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please, post `index.php`, `header.php` and `single.php` code.

Comment: Posted Gists for each file @alirezasafian

Comment: First, try to put Google Analytics script inside `head`.

Comment: Found it. It was a disabled cache plugin that was serving an old version of index.php, thanks for your help @alirezasafian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem: the index page does not have `meta viewport`. You need to add that in index page.

Comment: This is so strange, the `meta viewport` is dropping on this page for some reason. Its a wordpress theme, so `meta viewport` is being called in header.php - which is then included on index.php and the same method is being used in `single.php`. Interesting...

Comment: @buschschwick You should check the why `header` does not pass meta tag to the `index.php`.

Comment: Yes, I agree @alireza-safian but I'm not seeing any indication why this would be. The meta tag is not wrapped in any conditionals and is part of the normal header. For instance there is a stylesheet a line under that is pulling in fine.

Answer (score 3):

Change your @media from "screen" to "all". You are targeting all devices not only screens:

```
 @media all and (max-width: 640px){
 // your css
}
```

**EDIT:**

When you view your source code, you cant find any `meta` tag for "viewport". I used your code and added viewport in my editor and it worked just fine:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to fix the issue.

Comment: i noticed you did not include "all" in your @media.